# How to group data and plot line graphs

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-science

This is the first time I am using pandas and iPython notebook and was not able to figure out the correct search terms for my problem.

I have a `.xls` file for compile time data for 3 build-servers located at 3 sites `A`, `B` and `C`. These build servers compile multiple projects, so i will pick any specific project. Hence I need to plot data like this (for a specific project - not all in one graph, to keep it simple):

```
X-axis = date
Y-axis = average build time on that date

3 lines for sites A, B and C
```

What I have done so far :

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt 

file=  r'/home/abc/Downloads/request.xls'
df = pd.read_excel(file,parse_dates=['Date'])

build_times = df[['Date','site','project','Duration']]
build_group = build_times.groupby(['Date','site','project']).mean()
```

I need help on following :

1. how i select only successful builds
   if there is a column `status` with 0 and 1.
2. How to plot the lines for sites `A`,`B` and `C` (for specific project) with above mentioned X and Y axes.

**EDIT**

After the answer of @jezrael, I am able to get the following data

```
2017-03-27  A   project1    963.200000
            B   project2    4587.176471
            C   project2    1449.375000
            C   project1    1449.375000
  .......
2017-03-28  A   project1    93.200000
            B   project1    4787.176471
            C   project2    1339.375000
            C   project1    1749.375000
```

Comment: Can you add some sample data?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need first filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) or [`query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
build_group = build_times[build_times['status'] == 1]
                          .groupby(['Date','site','project'])['Duration'].mean()
```

Or:

```
build_group = build_times.query('status == 1')
                         .groupby(['Date','site','project'])['Duration'].mean()
```

Output is same as:

```
d={'Duration': [963.2, 4587.176471, 1449.375, 1449.375, 93.2, 4787.176471, 1339.375, 1749.375], 
'project': ['project1', 'project2', 'project2', 'project1', 'project1', 'project1', 'project2', 'project1'], 
'Date': [pd.Timestamp('2017-03-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-27 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-28 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-28 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-28 00:00:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-03-28 00:00:00')], 
'site': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C']}
build_group = pd.DataFrame(d).set_index(['Date','site','project'])['Duration']
print (build_group)
Date        site  project 
2017-03-27  A     project1     963.200000
            B     project2    4587.176471
            C     project2    1449.375000
                  project1    1449.375000
2017-03-28  A     project1      93.200000
            B     project1    4787.176471
            C     project2    1339.375000
                  project1    1749.375000
Name: Duration, dtype: float64
```

and then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with `level=1` (because `level==1` are `sites`) and select by [`xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html). Last [`plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
#for check column names for typos
print (build_group.index.get_level_values(2).unique().tolist())
['project1', 'project2']

p = 'project1'
build_group = build_group.unstack(level=1).xs(p, level=1, axis=0)
print (build_group)
site            A            B         C
Date                                    
2017-03-27  963.2          NaN  1449.375
2017-03-28   93.2  4787.176471  1749.375

build_group.plot()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Oh we can do nesting.. looks like its working. Now how can I pick specific project and plot line graphs for 3 sites?

Comment: I think yes, but code was typing without data. So is possible add `print (build_group.head())` to your question? If need help with selecting, but I think [`DataFrame.xs`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html) should help.

Comment: please see the EDIT

Comment: Thanks, I add `['Duration'].mean()` instaed `mean`.Please check if solution works. Thanks.

Comment: did you mean `build_group = build_group.unstack(level=1).xs(p, level=1, axis=0)` instead of `df`?

Comment: Sure, sorry, I change it.

Comment: it gives me `keyError project1`

Comment: It seems some typo in project names, can you chack it by `print (build_group.index.get_level_values(2).unique().tolist())` after `mean` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147690/discussion-between-insane-coder-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

The keyword is:

```
DataFrame.mean(axis=None, skipna=None, level=None, numeric_only=None, **kwargs)
```

Reference is given in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html)

Then you can do:

```
successful = df['success'] > 0
```

This will create a new dataframe `successful`. Where `success` is your column that has 1 or 0.

For (2), you can do the same, select only the column and plot it using `df.plot(*args)`